# Azure monitormanagementclient .net

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-monitoring

Using the preview package for Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor, I am trying to get ActivityLogs from Azure into a .NET application, but I am uncertain about what to input as "odataquery".

```
var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, secret);
var monitorClient = new MonitorManagementClient(serviceCreds);
monitorClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

var odataquery = "";
var activityLogs = await monitorClient.ActivityLogs.ListAsync(odataQuery: odataquery, cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);
```

What should I insert in the odataQuery variable, and where do I get this odataQuery from in Azure? A lot of things are great about Azure, but not documentation for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like below:

```
    //use DateTime to parse datetime.
    var startTime = DateTime.Parse("2020-03-05T01:00:00.00Z");
    var endTime = DateTime.Parse("2020-03-28T01:00:00.00Z");

    //it will throw errors if use the operator > or <, but works if using >= or <=
    var odataquery = new ODataQuery<EventData>(p => p.EventTimestamp >= startTime && p.EventTimestamp <= endTime);

    var events = client.ActivityLogs.List(odataquery);
```

**And here are some notes you need to take care of:**

1.When define `startTime` and `endTime`, you should use `DateTime.Parse()` method instead of `DateTimeOffset.Parse()`.

2.The `startTime` should not be more than 90 days ago.

3.When define `odataquery`, it will throw errors if you're using `> or <` operator. But it's ok to use `>= or <=` operator.

Comment: above code give error 'IActivityLogsOperations' does not contain a definition for 'List' and the best extension method overload 'AccountsOperationsExtensions.List(IAccountsOperations, ODataQuery<DataLakeAnalyticsAccountBasic>, string, bool?)' requires a receiver of type 'IAccountsOperations'

Comment: after little change in above code i was getting response, change as " var events = await client.ActivityLogs.ListAsync(odataQuery: Convert.ToString(odataquery));"